# How to get the latest record first in qldb?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-qldb

**Select * from Transactions where id='1234'**

How to get latest record first i.e. records in descending order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QLDB doesn't currently support ORDER BY (or LIMIT), so you'd have to execute that query and do the sort in your application code.